# Is converting to char is considered always narrowing?

Tags: java, type-conversion

I am studying for my exam and i just found out that converting from byte to char in java is considered narrowing. According to the book, the storage of char is the same as byte, but it's still considered narrowing. Can somebody explain why?

Also, Converting from Byte to char is also a narrowing! I thought that the if A>B then B<A this doesn't apply here right ?

I know it's a stupid question.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? I thought a char in Java was UTF-16, alternatively this could be byte -> unsigned char issue but thats a C/C++ issue these days. Character encodings in files might also make the original  statement true but this seems unlikely.

Comment: "According to the book, the storage of char is the same as byte" - then the book is wrong.

Comment: Is this a strictly Java question?  That's implied by how you worded your question, but you don't say it clearly, and you didn't use the `Java` tag.

Comment: i edited it now, sorry for not adding the tag, i also attached the picture from the book

Comment: Tell us what book this is so we can make sure never to read it.

Comment: Also, `Byte` and `byte` are very different things.

Comment: Looks like a typo to me. Note that in some contexts i.e. byte -> 7 bit ASCII character narrowing would occur but this is unlikely to be the issue the author was thinking of.

Comment: so is it wrong ? from byte to char is not narrowing ??

Comment: Your question is not stupid at all when you consider that your intuition is correct and you are being confused by bad information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737100/why-does-a-byte-in-java-i-o-can-represent-a-character

Comment: A `byte` is 8 bits, a `char` is 16 bits, so the storage for `char` is not the same as for `byte`. The book is wrong.

Comment: thank you guys, so i guess it's better to delete this question in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`byte` to `char` may effectively be considered a narrowing conversion in Java because it introduces the possibility for information loss. While it is true that `byte` is an 8-bit quantity and `char` is 16-bit, keep in mind that `char` is the only unsigned primitive type in Java. This means that converting a `byte` to a `char` will truncate off any negative values. The reverse conversion is also narrowing because any numbers greater than `127` will be truncated when converting to `byte`. Java does conversion differently than C++, where `signed` to `unsigned` just means that the compiler will interpret the bits differently, but the actual number does not change.

Comment: No prob. I still think the book is bad :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually conversion from `byte` to `char` requires *both* a widening and a narrowing conversion (one after the other). This is precisely what the Java language specification requires. In [section 5.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5):

> Casting contexts allow the operand of a cast operator (§15.16) to be converted to the type explicitly named by the cast operator.
>
> Casting contexts allow the use of one of:

(...)

> - a widening and narrowing primitive conversion (§5.1.4)

The table from the book looks incorrect (I'm assuming the caption is supposed to be "Java narrowing conversions"). There is no narrowing conversion from `byte` to `char`. The actual widening and narrowing primitive conversions are listed in the JLS sections [5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) and [5.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3).

Note that `char` can be converted to `byte` by a narrowing conversion alone, but `byte` cannot be converted to `char` by a widening conversion alone. (And, to make things just that extra bit complicated, conversion between `char` and `short` is a narrowing conversion in *both* directions!).

To answer your question succintly: **Yes**, primitive conversion to `char` is always a `narrowing` conversion - *but it may require a widening conversion to be performed first!*.

Answer (score 0):

Byte is a signed primitive type which means it can represent both negative and positive from values of -128 to 127.

Char is an unsigned primitive type which means it cannot represent negative values.

I’m reading the same book and my professor just covered this.

Therefore the book is not wrong it is correct.